# Rest service for Database

Tags: database, rest, apache-kafka

Sometimes clients, can't connect directly to the databases, (for example web js client - Qlik Sense Extensions,...)  but they really need direct data from databases. 
Good approach is to encapsulate database in REST service, this way, you can access data from those clients, and you don't need to give the client a database access.

If you are looking for more general solution, (not just for current project), I believe, there must be better solution, then for every database writing your own REST service ( althow I know how to write it and, and yes it is not that much work), because then you need to write your own services, maintain them,...

so:

If I want to have a REST service for serving the database data, what is the best solution?

To be more precise:

1. I don't want to write rest service by myself
2. I would need this service for multiple database (not just for one project)
3. I need that rest service is near real time (no cached data)

I am looking for some solution, that create (encapsulate) database (semi)automatically, so that I can plug my new database in my infrastructure quickly and with as little maintenance work as possible.

Is there a solution for this? 
I was looking at Kafka, but I am not sure if this is what I need,...

### EDIT:

For now, lat say I need it for postgres databases.

Comment: Which databases? What's driving this? Sounds like an odd set of requirements without more context.

Comment: What exactly do you need? A REST-layer on top of your db? 

With Kafka you can feed/stream data to/from your DB from Kafka topic using DB connectors.

Comment: From what I got from your question Kafka isn't the right thing to look at. It is a distributed log which solves a completly different problem than a REST API does

Comment: Thank you for your input. I edit my post, so I hope is more clear what I have in mind. I have to be honest, I didn't fully dive into Kafka, and don't understand yet, what is possible with it. But from quick read, it was looking promising as data strimmer (strimming from database to my client)...

Comment: From what I got out of your question, maybe Dremio, Streamsets, or Apache Nifi could fit your solution as far as a "web/http interface with no coding" is concerned

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if you've got a Kafka-shaped hole and you want to fix a Kafka-shaped nail in it, this is what it could look like :

You use a Change-Data-Capture (CDC) tool against your database to stream every change as it happens in the database (or specific tables) in realtime into Kafka. Once the data is in Kafka you can serve it up to any consumer (numerous client API libraries, plus a [REST proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#kafkarest-intro)).

You can stream multiple hetrogenous databases into Kafka to make disparate data available to the same consuming applications. You can use Apache [Kafka's Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) to even filter or join these inbound streams of data. You can also use [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-open-source-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/) to do this using a SQL-like stream processing language alone.

With the data in Kafka not only can you consume it with the consumer API or REST proxy, you can also land it to other data stores using [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html).

Since data is persisted in Kafka (retention based on time, size, or indefinitely with compacted topics), you can consume the same data independently from multiple consumers and connectors.

*But* all of this said…you don't have to use Kafka. There are simpler ways to access data out of a database if that's **all** you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your post. It was interesting. For now, I only need to get the database values, but I will keep in mind this. You said that there are simpler ways... can you present some of them?